# FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL works for fake email but not an actual email

Tags: php, html, sql, phpmyadmin

I write a fake email like name.fakegmail.com and it allows the email but i write my actual email and it's invalid. Any ideas of why this could be happening

```
function invalidEmail(string $email): bool
{
    return (bool) filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}
```

I expect the function to work correctly.

Comment: The result of your function is backwards. The name is `invalidEmail()`, but it returns true when the email is valid.

Comment: Note that `filter_var()` doesn't actually check if the email exists and can receive email. It just checks the if the address is syntactically valid.